# How to get a reference to the created DOM from a templateResult (not using custom elements)

Tags: javascript, frameworks, lit-html

For those crazy folks like me that wouldn't want for various reasons to use custom elements, is there a way to access the DOM related to a templateResult?

I tried to modify the templateResult's content before rendering but without success... I also looked into templateFactory, but it seems it's desinged for the ultimate (parent) templateResult rendered to a container, not nested templateResults.

```javascript
const componentA = {
    id: 'comp-a',  
    template(){ return html`<div>No ID yet</div>` }
};
const app = {
    template(){
        const tmpl = html`<main><div>${ componentA.template() }</div></main>`
        // here: use componentA.id to set top element's id
        // seems it's too late to change the template, DOM is already created?
        // so how to get a reference to the created DOM from a templateResult?
        return tmpl
    }
};
render( app.template(), document.body);
```

For example, how could I automatically set an id on the top element of componentA from its id?

Comment: So you want to obtain a reference to this element? -> `<div>No ID yet</div>`

Comment: Yes, is it possible?

Comment: I answered, let me know if I understood correctly your problem

Answer (score 0):

The thing is `lit-html` actually creates `TemplateResult`s which are just representations of the HTML that will be created once `render()` is called.

In this sense the `<div>` inside A's template has no particular "meaning" with respect to the `TemplateResult` representing it, but its instances can still be normally `querySelect`ed from the render container.

```
const tmpl = html`
  <main>
    <div>
      ${componentA.template()} <!-- This returns a TemplateResult -->
    </div>
  </main>
`;
```

You're still totally allowed to assign an id to the `<div>`:

```
const componentA = {
  // ...
  template() {
    return html`
      <div id="comp-a"></div>
    `;
  }
}
```

If you want to assign the id only at a later stage, you can pass it as argument to the function that creates A's template:

```
const componentA = {
  // ...
  template(id) {
    return html`
      <div id=${id}></div>
    `;
  }
}
```

Comment: My problem is trying to access a component DOM as a framework author perspective – i.e. not the one creating the HTML template, so I would need a way to query the component element (as a template or the real DOM) and make some "auto magic" changes...  Seems like custom element based components is the only way to have DOM access. This said with this reactive paradigm I found I almost never need to query the DOM

Comment: Technically you can access the `<template>` element created by lit-html with the [`TemplateResult#getTemplateElement()`](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/api/classes/lit_html.templateresult.html#gettemplateelement) method. But if you just need to update the DOM then lit-html's event and property bindings should be just fine

Comment: "... I tried to modify the templateResult's content before rendering but without success..."